# Como passar matriz charcomo parametro?

Tags: c

Estou fazendo dessa forma errada.Gosaria de saber como poderia passar esse vetor de nomes para trabalhar na funcao?

```
void primeiro_ex(int *lista,char **nomes){}



void main(){
    int notas[60];
     char nomes[60][60];
    primeiro_ex(notas,nomes);

}
```

Comment: Considere a sugestão de C: `main()` faz exatamente isso para todo programa e a lista de argumentos é... `int argc, char** argv`

Answer (score 1):

Tempos atrás eu postei algo assim, em [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) e só traduzi as mensagens para postar de novo aqui.

O programa cria um bloco de parâmetros e chama uma função de nome pobre :( `igual_main()` com os mesmos argumentos.

Assim pode ver como criar o bloco, como aumentar dinamicamente e como liberar ao final. É o que se usa para carregar por exemplo um texto linha a linha para a memória. A alocação é feita em blocos para ficar mais eficiente.

#### Sáida do exemplo

```
Bloco estendido para um total de 8 ponteiros
Bloco estendido para um total de 12 ponteiros
Bloco estendido para um total de 16 ponteiros
Bloco estendido para um total de 20 ponteiros
        17 strings no bloco:
                1 de 17: 'nome do programa'
                2 de 17: 'Criando'
                3 de 17: 'um'
                4 de 17: 'bloco'
                5 de 17: 'de'
                6 de 17: 'strings'
                7 de 17: ','
                8 de 17: 'do'
                9 de 17: 'modo'
                10 de 17: 'como o '
                11 de 17: 'sistema'
                12 de 17: 'faz'
                13 de 17: 'para'
                14 de 17: 'main()'
                15 de 17: 'em todo '
                16 de 17: 'programa'
                17 de 17: 'C'
        20 ponteiros alocados
        17 argumentos lidos
        3 ponteiros a liberar
        Tamanho total ajustado para 17 ponteiros
        Chamando igual_main() com esses argumentos

        Em "main()": 17 argumentos

       0        'nome do programa'
       1        'Criando'
       2        'um'
       3        'bloco'
       4        'de'
       5        'strings'
       6        ','
       7        'do'
       8        'modo'
       9        'como o '
      10        'sistema'
      11        'faz'
      12        'para'
      13        'main()'
      14        'em todo '
      15        'programa'
      16        'C'


        "main()" retornou 0
        Agora libera o bloco todo e encerra


F i m
```

#### O programa C

```
#define _BLOCO_ 4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int     argc;
    char**  argv;
}   Vetor_de_strings;

int igual_main(int, char**);

int main(void)
{
    const int   n_parm = 16;
    const char* strings_de_teste[] =
    {
        "Criando", "um", "bloco", "de",
        "strings", ",", "do", "modo",
        "como o ", "sistema", "faz", "para" ,
        "main()",  "em todo ", "programa", "C"
    };

    /*
    memoria e alocada em blocos de _BLOCO_ ponteiros.
    Sempre que preciso um novo bloco eh. Ao final o bloco 
    eh ajustado para o tamanho exato e os ponteiros nao 
    usados sao liberados via free()

    Ex: para 12 strings e _BLOCO_ 5:  3 blocos serao alocados
    para um total de 15. Ao final da criacao os 3 ponteiros 
    nao usados sao liberados

    */
    Vetor_de_strings ex; // exemplo
    int N = _BLOCO_;
    ex.argc = 0;
    ex.argv = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * _BLOCO_);
    const char* program_name = "nome do programa";
    ex.argv[ex.argc] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(program_name));
    strcpy(ex.argv[ex.argc], program_name);
    ex.argc += 1; // 1st arg. That was easy

    // carrega o vetor argv
    for (int i = 0; i < n_parm; i += 1)
    {   // cada um
        if (ex.argc >= N)
        {   // bloco cheio
            N = N + _BLOCO_;
            char* new_block = realloc(ex.argv, (N * sizeof(char*)));
            printf("Bloco estendido para um total de %d ponteiros\n", N);
            ex.argv = (char**)new_block;
        };
        ex.argv[ex.argc] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(strings_de_teste[i]));
        strcpy(ex.argv[ex.argc], strings_de_teste[i]);
        ex.argc += 1;
    };  // for()
    printf("\t%d strings no bloco:\n", ex.argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.argc; i += 1)
    {
        printf("\t\t%d de %d: '%s'\n", 1 + i, ex.argc, ex.argv[i]);
    };

    printf("\t%d ponteiros alocados\n", N);
    printf("\t%d argumentos lidos\n", ex.argc);
    if (N == ex.argc)
        printf("\tNada a liberar\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\t%d ponteiros a liberar\n", N - ex.argc);
        char* new_size = realloc(ex.argv, (ex.argc * sizeof(char*)));
        printf("\tTamanho total ajustado para %d ponteiros\n", ex.argc);
        ex.argv = (char**)new_size;
    };
    printf("\tChamando igual_main() com esses argumentos\n");
    int res = igual_main(ex.argc, ex.argv);
    printf("\n\n\t\"main()\" retornou %d\n", res);
    printf("\tAgora libera o bloco todo e encerra\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.argc; i += 1)
        free(ex.argv[i]);
    free(ex.argv);
    printf("\n\nF i m\n");
    return 0;
};

int igual_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\n\tEm \"main()\": %d argumentos\n\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1)
        printf("%8d\t'%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
};  // nova_main()
//fim
```